# What is wrong with my double pulse test setup in LTspice?

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, simulation, gate-driving, losses

I am trying to make double pulse test measurements in LTspice using the spice model of a MOSFET and gate driver we are using in our actual design. My setup seems to be not working as nothing is appearing on the gate of the low side MOSFET which is the device under test.

I have used the same components which we have used in our actual design.  The spice models I am using are from Infineon. It is strange that my setup is not working. Can anyone here please advise what could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Alison please read this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Alison did you try fixing your schematic as per my answer? Are you aware that the normal protocol on stack exchange sites is to accept answers that are correct or raise a comment seeking clarification. I'm sure you don't want site users to think you are are mean-spirited about this sort of thing in case help dries up.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, Thank you. problem is solved now and sorry I am new here so i did not knew about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *but my setup seems to be not working as nothing is appearing on gate
> of low side mosfet which is device under test*

LIN is the input to the [AUIRS21814 low side driver](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/auirs2181s.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355bf689415b6) and it is connected to 0 volts: -

[image]

> *Can anyone here please advise what could be the problem?*

This means that there can be no LO output to drive the low-side MOSFET.